# Sidekiq Doesn't Create a PID file

Tags: ruby, config, pid, sidekiq

In order to stop Sidekiq I need to use:

`$bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /Users/me/Documents/sites/some_site/tmp/pid/sidekiq.pid 20`

I am telling Sidekiq to create a pid file in a config.yml file:

```
#/Users/me/Documents/sites/some_site/config.yml
:pidfile: /Users/me/Documents/sites/some_site/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:concurrency: 25
```

And telling Sidekiq where this config file is using:

`$ bundle exec sidekiq -C /Users/me/Documents/sites/some_site/config.yml`

**However when I run Sidekiq it does not create a .pid file, so I can't stop it. So why doesn't it create a .pid file?**

Answer (score 8):

Try replacing that absolute path with this:

```
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
```

Second, ensure the user that will run sidekiq has the proper write permissions to write to that directory. You can chmod 777 temporarily to test to see if permissions is the issue.

Here is an example config yml file for Sidekiq. Make sure you specify a queue too. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/config.yml

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As I mention in my question, I'm already using a config.yml file. however I've changed the path to the pid file as you suggested and added a default queue. I've also chmodded the dir to allow read/write to all. However despite all this, no pid file is written.

Comment: Am I completely misunderstanding this? Should Sidekiq write the pid file or should I create it and place it in that location for Sidekiq to use?

Comment: @emerak The pid file is created by the system.

Answer (score 6):

To use a pidfile, you should launch sidekiq as a daemon. When on your rails root directory launch sidekiq with this command :

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -e development
```

You can replace development by the appropriate rails environment.

You should also specify a logfile in you sikekiq configure (config/sidekiq.yml). Exemple :

```
concurrency: 5
development:
  pidfile: tmp/pids/sidekiq_development.pid
  logfile: log/sidekiq_development.log
beta:
  pidfile: /var/run/sidekiq_beta.log
  logfile: log/sidekiq_beta.pid
staging:
  pidfile: /var/run/sidekiq_stating.pid
  logfile: log/sidekiq_staging.log
production:
  pidfile: /var/run/sidekiq_production.pid
  logfile: log/sidekiq_production.log
  concurrency: 50
```

If you are on Debian and you need a launch script, you can use this Gist, I put,  on Github : https://gist.github.com/alain75007/5517948

Comment: FYI: `-d` (daemon) is removed in Sidekiq 6.0